# Add Virtual Directory to IIS Express with launchsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

we want to add a virtual directory to our web application in debug mode.

ATM we added the virtual directory to the applicationhost.config file in the .vs directory. This works, but every developer must add the virtual directorys.
We also have the launchsettings.json which comes with ASP Core and is under source control. So the idea is to add these virtual directorys to that file.
Is this possible? I only found solutions to add the virtual directorys via applicationhost.config.
Thank you

Comment: I don't think `launchsettings.json` has that feature.